# Adding a C wire to Nest learning thermostat 3rd gen

Tags: wiring, thermostat, thermostat-c-wire

I'm trying to add a C wire to my Nest thermostat, I already had the C cable on both ends but it wasn't connected, I went to the attic and connected the blue wire from the thermostat wiring to the C terminal, however, it already had a red cable connected to it but I read that it was fine to add the C wire.

Then on the other end (thermostat) the red wire is going to the RC and the blue C wire that I connected is going to the C terminal (of course) everything looked fine, but when the thermostat turns the ac on it makes an electric sound, will last 5 seconds on and then turn off again, turn on and turn off again, etc.

I had to disconnect the C wire from the thermostat, and it's working again, but this is a temporary fix since I need to connect the c wire again.
Here is the [image]for reference, for some reason I think the red wire connected to the C terminal is connected to the black wire connected to the R terminal. I don't know if this could be causing the issue but it was something that got my attention. **(Edit)** I just checked and the Red wire connected to the C terminal going to the outside unit. [image: Here is another image for reference]

My question is, what could be causing the issue with the thermostat when the C wire is connected? is it ok to have the C wire and that red wire both connected to the C terminal?

Comment: It's hard to tell from that pic if the red `C` & black `R` wires are connected under that orange wire nut, but since you are right there, I'll be you can tell. Since that's the only question you've asked, that's probably the only answer we can give. If you have an actual question, please [edit] your question to _clearly_ ask it. Also, some formatting to help make this more readable would help, as well as including the brand/model of the furnace/AC units involved. We have a _lot_ of questions about C-wire installations, looking through those may give you your answer.

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment, this is my first post and I know it's far from perfect but the feedback is much appreciated. I just edited the post and I hope it makes more sense now. As for the other questions about C wire installations, I couldn't find an answer to my problem online. Again, thank you so much, and let me know if there is something else I can add. I'm not home right now so I don't know the furnace/ac brands and model but I could add it once I'm back. @FreeMan

Comment: Welcome, please help us to help you. Use flash light and take those pics again. You seem to have some device that should activate when the AC is on. What is it ? It is connected with white, together with yellow on the Y screw. You also have the R-black connected to the red and going to the C terminal. From the right to left. Y is cooling-yellow, G is Fan only-green, R is 24 Volt-black, C is the common- it should be blue only, W is heating- white again.

Comment: One really useful picture would be the wiring at the thermostat, but we're assuming you have followed the standard color scheme. To clarify some of the wiring, you likely have a float switch which is why your R at the board starts off black and then becomes red at the wire nut. The red/white coming off the board (in your hand) go the condenser; ignore their colors for your purposes. It sounds like the wiring is correct, but the Nest may be "shorting" upon activating when the C-wire is connected. Upload that last pic when you get a chance.

Comment: Yes, can you get us better photos and/or a wiring diagram of your setup please?